# Symfony 2 FOSUserBundle with rest login and registration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have gone through lots of stackoveflow question and articles, but can't find a suitable answer.

I'm using fosuserbundle, hwiouthbundle and lexikjwt bundle.

I'm developing an api based on symfony which will be consumed by an android app and angular app.

Now I need the register and login system with fosuserbundle facebook login with hwiouthbundle and api protection with lexikjwt bundle.

I have implemented fosuserbundle and hwiouthbundke and both working without even writing user controller. But I need this with rest not with form. But I can't out type : rest in router.

Now how can I login, register user with fosuserbundle with rest? I don't want to use fosouth server. Just need registration and login with api not rest  from web.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, if you want register user manually using FOSUserBundle, create a controller and add a register method :

```
// Acme/AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController

public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $data = $request->request->all();

    // Do a check for existing user with userManager->findByUsername

    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setUsername($data['username']);
    // ...
    $user->setPlainPassword($data['password']);
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $userManager->updateUser($user);

    return $this->generateToken($user, 201);
}
```

And, the generateToken method

```
protected function generateToken($user, $statusCode = 200)
{
    // Generate the token
    $token = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager')->create($user)

    $response = array(
        'token' => $token,
        'user'  => $user // Assuming $user is serialized, else you can call getters manually
    );

    return new JsonResponse($response, $statusCode); // Return a 201 Created with the JWT.
}
```

And the route

```
security_register:
    path: /api/register
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeAppBundle:Security:registerAction }
    methods: POST
```

Configure the firewall same as login

```
// app/config/security.yml

firewalls:
    // ...
    register:
        pattern: ^/api/register
        anonymous: true
        stateless: true
    // ...

access_control:
    // ...
    - { path: ^/api/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

For login, juste use the `check_path` of your FOSUser login firewall.

For more information about the token generation, see [JWTManager](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Services/JWTManager.php#L65). 
Hope this help you.

**EDIT**

If you want a full example of LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle + FOSUserBundle + FOSRestBundle implementation see my [symfony-rest-api](https://github.com/chalasr/symfony-rest-api)

Comment: Guys, stop using JWT for sessions. It is made for single sign-on and third-party authentication, not for sessions. See http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/.

Comment: @thomaskonrad people do what they want, that doesn't make the answer bad at all... unjustified down vote, at worst it should be on the question.

Comment: the missing warning makes it bad in my eyes. But fair enogh, I downvoted the question as well.

Comment: Except that this is not using JWT to replace sessions, but to deliver authorizations from a stateless webserver (php) to a third party application (android in this case), and could very well do that for many other apps. I don't get the point here...